# NestJS : Passport LinkedIn strategy with graphql

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, passport.js, nestjs

I have nestjs application running on typescript, Graphql, Postgres with Jwt strategy defined, now I need to workout LinkedIn strategy with it. I am not really sure where to start with it, there are a couple of [packages](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-linkedin) available but they are missing the Graphql part and they are mostly pointing to API endpoints on local like `/auth/linkedin/callback`, I would like to know here and how to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [LinkedIn's OAuth documentatioin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) you'll see that LinkedIn needs to know about a callback url for when authorization attempts are successful. You'll also see that the response for the initial authroization call (what calls your callback URL)  is a GET request that doesn't conform to GraphQL format, so you **have** to implement a REST endpoint for this.

This is pretty true for *most* OAuth2.0 calls. You need to implement them in REST, not GraphQL. If you *really* wanted to, you could take the REST call and do some transformation to make it a GQL call, then forward it on to your GQL server, but that's still a REST endpoint you've got in your server.